# How can i see my test logs in the console log of jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, automated-tests

I'm running my junit test for my android app throw jenkins. In case a test fails I can only see the stacktrace  which sometimes doesn't help me to understand why My test was failed. I added some logs in my code so I can debug my test when I run them on my local machine but I want to be able to see those logs in the Jenkins console output so I can realize what went wrong when my test fails.

Comment: Do you see the logs when you run the tests on your local environment?(your IDE console, or terminal)

Comment: yes. I can see it on Android Monitor console in my android studio.

Comment: it's hard to tell what is the problem, but as a work around you can print the log in to a log file and then just "cat/type" this file.

Comment: I thought about this solution.I'll give it a try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but I have found a solution.
I wrap `Log` class into a custom class (`Logger`).

Then I wrap the Log methods like:

```
public static void d(String tag, String message) {
    log(LOG.DEBUG, tag, message);
}
```

Then log looks like:

```
private static void log(LOG logLevel, Object message) {
        LOG_LINES.add(new LogLine(logLevel, tag, content));

        switch (logLevel) {
            case ERROR:
                Log.e(tag, content);
                break;
            case WARNING:
                Log.w(tag, content);
                break;
            case INFO:
                Log.i(tag, content);
                break;
            case DEBUG:
                Log.d(tag, content);
                break;
            case VERBOSE:
                Log.v(tag, content);
                break;
       }
    }
```

with `LOG_LINES` a CopyOnWriteArrayList
and `LogLine` a holder of the log data.

Finally, the logs are displayed in Jenkins (in the HTML Report) by using a custom test `Runner`. Simply add the Annotation `@RunWith(MyLoggingTestRunner.class)` to the test classes with :

```
public class MyLoggingTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyLoggingTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }


    @Override
    protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        //override to override errors with logs
        Description description = describeChild(method);
        if (method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) != null) {
            notifier.fireTestIgnored(description);
        } else {
            run(methodBlock(method), description, notifier);
        }
    }

    protected void run(Statement statement, Description description, RunNotifier notifier) {
        EachTestNotifier eachNotifier = new EachTestNotifier(notifier, description);
        eachNotifier.fireTestStarted();
        try {
            statement.evaluate();
        } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
            eachNotifier.addFailedAssumption(e);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            String throwableMessage = e.getMessage();
            String message = "\nLast logs :\n" + logsToString() + "\n\nStackTrace :\n" + e.getClass() + (TextUtils.isEmpty(throwableMessage) ? "" : ":" + throwableMessage);

            try {
                Field detailMessage = Throwable.class.getDeclaredField("detailMessage");
                detailMessage.setAccessible(true);
                detailMessage.set(e, message);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
            eachNotifier.addFailure(e);
        } finally {
            eachNotifier.fireTestFinished();
        }
    }


    private static String logsToString() {
        List<LogLine> logs = Logger.getLogs();
        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String sep = "";
        for (LogLine logLine : logs) {
            logBuilder.append(sep).append(logLine.toString());
            sep = "\n";
        }
        return logBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

I hope it works since I adapted my code trying to explain it in a simple way.